# Necessary and sufficient condition for a $C^*$-embedded subset to be $C$-embedded

Tags: general-topology

One of the necessary and sufficient conditions for a $C^*$-embedded subset to be $C$-embedded is expressed in following lemma,

> A $C^*$-embedded subset $Y$ of space $X$ is $C$-embedded in $X$ iff $Y$ is completely separated from every zero-set in $X$ disjoint from it.

necessity proved by definition. But I have 2 questions about the converse.

let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function on $Y$. Take a homeomorphism 
$\varphi$ of $\mathbb{R}$ onto the open interval $(0, 1)$. Then $\varphi\circ f$ is a continuous bounded function on $Y$, so 
it admits an extension to a continuous function $g$ on $X$. Clearly,

$$Z=\{x\in X:\vert g(x)\vert\geq1\}$$

is a zero-set in $X$ disjoint from $Y$, so by our hypothesis, there exists a continuous function 
$h$ on $X$ with values in $[0, 1 ]$ equal to $0$ on $Z$ and to $1$ on $Y$. Then the restriction of $g\cdot h$ to $Y$ 
coincides with $\varphi\circ f$ and satisfies $\vert(g \cdot h)(x)\vert \leq 1$ for each $x\in X$. Therefore, $\varphi^{-1}\circ(g\cdot h)$ 
is a continuous extension of $f$ over $X$.

1. Why $Z$ is a zero-set in $X$?
2. For each $x\in X$, $\vert(g \cdot h)(x)\vert \leq 1$. Is it true?

Comment: In order to take $\varphi^{-1}\circ(g\cdot h)(x)$ you should have $0<(g \cdot h)(x)<1$ for each $x\in X$. So I guess you should take a homeomorphism  $\varphi$ of $\mathbb{R}$ onto the open interval $(-1, 1)$ instead. Then in order to take $\varphi^{-1}\circ(g\cdot h)(x)$ you should have $-1<(g \cdot h)(x)<1$ for each $x\in X$. This should be because if $x\in Z$ then $h(x)=0$ and if $x\not\in Z$ then $|g(x)|<1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Note that every closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a zero-set, and zero sets are closed under inverse images by continuous maps.  (We have that $Z = g^{-1} [ ( - \infty , -1 ] \cup [ 1 , + \infty ) ]$.)
2. As $0 \leq h(x) \leq 1$, if $| ( g \cdot h ) (x) | > 1$ it must be that $| g ( x ) | > 1$, but then $x \in Z$ meaning that $h(x) = 0$ so $( g \cdot h ) ( x ) = 0$.