# $C^{*}$ -embedded and $C$-embedded

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

The set $  C= C ( X ) $ of all continuous, real valued functions on a topological space$ X$  will be provided with an algebraic structure and an order struture.The subset $C^{*} = C^{*} (X)$ of $C(X)$ , consisting of all bounded function in $C(X)$.

A Zero-set means:  $ Z ( f ) =  f^{-1 } ( \{ 0 \} ) = \{ x \in X \vert f ( x ) = 0 \}$ , $ f \in C (X) $

**Does anyone help me to prove the following problems?**

> 1: **Is every $C^{*}$ -embedded zero - set,  $C$-embedded?**
>
> 2:**Is a subset $S$  of  $\mathbb{R}$ $C$-embedded ($C^{*}$-embedded$ )if and only if it is closed?**
>
> 3:**Is $C(S)$ a homomorphism image of $C(X)$, if a (nonempty) subset $S$ of $X$ is $C$ - embedded in $X$?**

Answer (score 2):

1) I don’t know an answer, but the following criterion may be helpful for you. I recall that two subsets $A$ and $B$ of a topological space are called *completely separated* if there exists a continuous function $f:X\to [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ for each $x\in A$ and $f(x)=1$ for each $x\in B$. According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330169/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-a-c-embedded-subset-to-be-c-embedde) question, a $C^*$-embedded subset $Y$ of space $X$ is $C$-embedded in $X$ iff $Y$ is completely separated from every zero-set in $X$ disjoint from it.

2) Each $C^*$-embedded subset of $\Bbb R$ is closed by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2530739/71850) answer. Conversely, each closed subset of $\Bbb R$ (or, more generally, of an arbitrary normal space) is $C$-embedded by Tietze-Urysohn extension theorem (see below its proof from Engelkings’ “General topology”).

[image]

[image]

3) It is easy to check that for each subset $S$ of the space $X$ the restriction map $r:f\mapsto f|S$ preserves all four arithmetic operations and if $f,g\in C(X)$ and $f\le g$, that is $f(x)\le g(x)$ for each point $x\in X$ then $f|S\le g|S$, so the map $r_S$ should be a homomorphism. Moreover, the map $r_S$ is sujective iff the set $S$ is $C$-embedded in $X$.